# Callback methods - Why are life cycle methods called as callback methods?

Tags: android, lifecycle

There are lifecycle callback methods in android. A callback method is defined as a method which is passed as an argument to another so that it can be called later.

1. Why are lifecycle methods (e.g. lifecycle methods of an activity) called as callback methods.
2. In android and so the sequence in which the program runs is in the hands of the user, i.e. when the user clicks on the launcher icon of an application, its `onCreate()` lifecycle callback method is called. Likewise `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onResume()` etc. are called in response to user's actions.

Does the system call (invoke) the `onCreate()` when the user touches the launcher icon, or does the program calls it?

Comment: Obviously the system. First do your research a bit. The documentation has a detailed discription about activity life cycle. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: @agile: I did my research, I have read this as well. I was still confused! You should not have given a negative ranking!

Comment: @agile And I did not ask about the life cycle at all. My question was it being a "call back" method. My research told me that call back methods are those passed as arguments to other methods!

Comment: And neither did any other question on stackoverflow.com address my question. I am confused about this matter since days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term callback describes the mechanism used by android to handle events.These methods are declared by the app and then the app goes about with other things. At the appropriate moment, that is when the event happens the android system calls back into the app's code and executes it.